C#. Могут ли переменные, классы и (др.) названые на кириллице быть чем-то опасны и проблематичны?
К примеру:
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int переменная= Класс.Факт(6);
    }
    
}
public static class Класс
{
    public static int Факт(int Исходное)
    {
        if (Исходное < 1) return Исходное;
        int b = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= Исходное; i++)
        {
            b = b * i;
        }
        return b;
    }

}

Может ли оно перестать работать должным образом в какой-то момент?

На мой взгляд это опасно тем, что из-за отхода от единого стиля какие-то штуки могут быть названы не так как ожидается, особенно если где-то в названиях перемешается русский и английский, потом поиском будет тяжело что-то найти. Когда всё заведомо на английском таких приколов обычно не бывает, а если и бывают, их быстро исправляют.

Как тут уже говорили, лучше избегать такой ситуации. Надо бы проверить, но мне кажется, что при работе с исходным кодом в Линуксе без установленной нужной локали может что-то сломаться. Но на практике вряд ли Вы попадёте в такую ситуацию.

Можно в резюме прямо писать "пишу C# переменные на русском". От работодателей отбоя не будет. (нет)

Китайцы этот подход практикуют. Очень весело с их кодом работать.

@Uranus вот только хотел об этом написать. Да, китайский C# - то ещё приключение, хоть расширение под студию пиши, чтобы иероглифы переводило.

я работаю во Франции, мы сотрудничаем с Испанией, где один из наших передовых программистов пишет код на испанском. Это допустимо да, но это больно. Я не владею должным образом английским, но мой код полностью включая комментарии на английском. Признаюсь, иногда я придумываю переменные, которые потом мне надо перевести(спустя ну скажем год, зато все в комманде понимают сразу), но так учится язык и честно это что то, к чему мы не готовы, хотя возможно все, и может быть вскоре мы узнаем новый язык программирования на чисто русском, может тогда мы станем профессиональней даже, кто знает...

@Dev18 Да был такой язык чисто на русском, но учебный. По типу Basic-а или Pascal-я. Ершов что ли его написал.

@CrazyElf 1С...

@aepot А, ну да. Слона то я...

На практике использование переменных, классов и методов с именами на кириллице в C# возможно / допустимо / практикуется - факт.
перестанет ли оно работать

в какой-то момент?

добавлю ссылку на спецификацию о которой указал в комментарии @Pavel Mayorov
Вероятность запрета на использование русских символов в идентификаторах C# крайне мала по нескольким причинам. C# поддерживает Unicode, что позволяет использовать символы из различных языков, включая кириллицу, что делает язык более доступным для международного сообщества разработчиков. Кроме того, нарушение обратной совместимости и отсутствие значительных технических проблем с использованием кириллических символов делает такой запрет маловероятным. Разработчики языка, как правило, сосредоточены на расширении функциональности и улучшении удобства использования, а не на введении новых ограничений.

Тем не менее, теоретически возможно всё. Например, в целях унификации и стандартизации, могли бы быть введены ограничения, но это должно быть тщательно обосновано и согласовано с сообществом разработчиков, чтобы избежать негативных последствий и обеспечить плавный переход

Однако следует обратить внимание на некотрые аспекты - это может привести к определённым проблемам и неудобствам, особенно при работе в команде или при разработке крупных проектов.

можно выделить пару основных моментов риска:
a) Некоторые IDE могут не поддерживать полностью кириллицу. Это может привести к неожиданному поведению или ошибкам в IDE.
b) Возможны проблемы при сборке или запуске проекта на других платформах или в других операционных системах, особенно если они не поддерживают полностью Unicode и кириллицу. Обычно это не проблема, так как C# поддерживает Unicode, но стоит быть внимательным к настройкам среды разработки и кодировкам файлов.
теоретически вы можете использовать кирилицу, но рекомендуется придерживаться общепринятых стандартов латиницы для повседневного программирования на C#
статья с habr, тут больше "за", но в комментариях, вот пример => При попытке написать IУченик он выводит Шученик - речь о неудобстве постоянно менять раскладку, и есть автоперключатели, которые не всегда корректно интерпретируют
ссылаясь на голосование 65 программистов мы видим, что 58 процентов против такой практики, интересно почитать комментарии, и реальные случаи
вот общий вопрос на нашем сайте я подметила для себя случай в ответе с двумя переменными (a и а - машинальная возможность, которая впоследствии может принести часы дебага)

Да с чего неизвестно-то? Спецификация языка разрешает в идентификаторах любые символы категории "Letter". И от платформы или ОС классификация символов Юникода не зависит (по крайней мере, не в части кириллицы).

@PavelMayorov, а вы уверенны, что она не изменится через 5 лет ?

Да, уверен. Никто не меняет базовую спецификацию языка с нарушением обратной совместимости просто потому что ему это захотелось.

Кстати, встречный вопрос: а вообще хоть в чём-нибудь вы уверены, если для вас спецификация языка - пустой звук и нечто изменчивое?

Павел, соглашусь, что обратная совместимость является важным аспектом при разработке и эволюции языков программирования  и мало кто будет менять вот так сразу,  однако языки программирования должны адаптироваться к новым требованиям и вызовам, чтобы оставаться полезными и актуальными для разработчиков. Вы старайтесь не переходить на личность, "в чем-нибудь" мы не затрагиваем, но не упускаем возможности вероятности.

я заведомо выделила  ===> в какой-то момент

поправила, так лучше ?

Все доводы и прочие технические рассуждения перечёркивает один маленький факт - когда ты опенсорц или работаешь в международной команде, код на кириллице, и даже комменты на русском в нём просто никто из не-русскоязычных коллег не поймёт.

мне захотелось дококпаться самой до истины, поэтому я затронула технические аспекты
